# C++: generate gaussian distribution

Tags: c++, gaussian, normal-distribution

I would like to know if in C++ standard libraries there is any **gaussian distribution** number generator, or if you have any code snippet to pass.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A C code snippet is available in a similar, [later question (click here)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995894/normalgaussian-distribution-function-in-c/23609868#23609868)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The standard library does not. Boost.Random does, however. I'd use that if I were you.

Answer (score 13):

C++ Technical Report 1 adds support for random number generation. So if you're using a relatively recent compiler (visual c++ 2008 GCC 4.3), chances are that it is available out of the box.

See [here](http://www.johndcook.com/cpp_TR1_random.html) for sample usage of `std::tr1::normal_distribution` (and many more).

Comment: If it is not there yet, you can find it as part of Boost, too: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_tr1/subject_list.html#boost_tr1.subject_list.random

Answer (score 6):

The GNU Scientific Libraries has this feature. [GSL - Gaussian Distribution](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/The-Gaussian-Distribution.html)

Comment: Lol, I wrote that before I looked up the answer... I guess I should change it :)

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this question changes with C++11 which has the [random header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) which includes [std::normal_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution). Walter Brown's paper [N3551, Random Number Generation in C++11](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/03/n3551-random-number-generation) is probably one of the better introductions to this library.

The following code demonstrates how to use this header (*[see it live](http://rextester.com/TGGW54402)*):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;

    std::mt19937 e2(rd());

    std::normal_distribution<> dist(2, 2);

    std::map<int, int> hist;
    for (int n = 0; n < 10000; ++n) {
        ++hist[std::floor(dist(e2))];
    }

    for (auto p : hist) {
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << std::setw(2)
                  << p.first << ' ' << std::string(p.second/200, '*') << '\n';
    }
}
```

I provide a more general set of examples to random number generation in C++11 in my answer to [C++ random float number generation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17798317/1708801) with an example in Boost and using `rand()` as well.