# C++: TR1 vs GSL vs Boost for statistical distributions?

Tags: c++, random

in my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109446/c-generate-gaussian-distribution) post I was asking how to generate numbers following a normal distribution.

Since I have also other distributions to generate and I saw 3 libraries might provide them ([GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-Number-Distributions.html), TechnicalReport1(doc link?), [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/libraries.htm#Math)), I was wondering which one you would choose.

As a side note: the reference platform for my application is a GNU/Linux system and performance is a matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some notes on getting started with [random number generation using C++ TR1](http://www.johndcook.com/cpp_TR1_random.html).

Answer (score 4):

Take Boost it is quite popular and well designed for C++.

GSL is very good library that gives tools far behind distributions, but it is covered by GPL (not LGPL) meaning that if you want to develop non-GPL applications and distribute them, you can't.

Answer (score 2):

Mersenne twister gives uniformly distributed numbers. There are two common approaches to generating normally distributed numbers from them:

1. [Box-Muller transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-Muller_method)
2. [Ziggurat method](http://seehuhn.de/pages/ziggurat)

In my experience, the Ziggurat is 2x faster in Java, because it calls slow log/exp functions much less often than Box-Muller. I don't know how it is in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Boost is nice because it's cross platform. Honestly, though, if you just need the numbers to not be cryptographically secure, a mersenne twister will be very fast from any of those libraries. If it's a bottleneck, just do some tests to find which is fastest.