# Implementing Box-Mueller random number generator in C#

Tags: c#, random, non-uniform-distribution

From [this question: Random number generator which gravitates numbers to any given number in range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816985/random-number-generator-which-gravitates-numbers-to-any-given-number-in-range) I did some research since I've come across such a random number generator before. All I remember was the name "Mueller", so I guess I found it, here:

- [Box-Mueller transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform)

I can find numerous implementations of it in other languages, but I can't seem to implement it correctly in C#.

This page, for instance, [The Box-Muller Method for Generating Gaussian Random Numbers](http://foxtrot.dpem.tuc.gr/~aboud/gaussian.html) says that the code should look like this (this is not C#):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

double gaussian(void)
{
   static double v, fac;
   static int phase = 0;
   double S, Z, U1, U2, u;

   if (phase)
      Z = v * fac;
   else
   {
      do
      {
         U1 = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
         U2 = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;

         u = 2. * U1 - 1.;
         v = 2. * U2 - 1.;
         S = u * u + v * v;
      } while (S >= 1);

      fac = sqrt (-2. * log(S) / S);
      Z = u * fac;
   }

   phase = 1 - phase;

   return Z;
}
```

Now, here's my implementation of the above in C#. Note that the transform produces 2 numbers, hence the trick with the "phase" above. I simply discard the second value and return the first.

```
public static double NextGaussianDouble(this Random r)
{
    double u, v, S;

    do
    {
        u = 2.0 * r.NextDouble() - 1.0;
        v = 2.0 * r.NextDouble() - 1.0;
        S = u * u + v * v;
    }
    while (S >= 1.0);

    double fac = Math.Sqrt(-2.0 * Math.Log(S) / S);
    return u * fac;
}
```

My question is with the following specific scenario, where my code doesn't return a value in the range of 0-1, and I can't understand how the original code can either.

- u = 0.5, v = 0.1
- S becomes `0.5*0.5 + 0.1*0.1` = `0.26`
- fac becomes ~`3.22`
- the return value is thus ~`0.5 * 3.22` or ~`1.6`

That's not within `0 .. 1`.

What am I doing wrong/not understanding?

If I modify my code so that instead of multiplying `fac` with `u`, I multiply by `S`, I get a value that ranges from 0 to 1, but it has the wrong distribution (seems to have a maximum distribution around 0.7-0.8 and then tapers off in both directions.)

Comment: Note that I've checked a couple of examples of the above code, usually in C or Java, and they all look pretty much the same.

Comment: Are you sure the C code generates exactly what you want?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code is fine. Your mistake is thinking that it should return values exclusively within `[0, 1]`. The (standard) normal distribution is a distribution with nonzero weight on the entire real line. That is, values outside of `[0, 1]` are possible. In fact, values within `[-1, 0]` are just as likely as values within `[0, 1]`, and moreover, the complement of `[0, 1]` has about 66% of the weight of the normal distribution. Therefore, 66% of the time we expect a value outside of `[0, 1]`.

Also, I think this is not the Box-Mueller transform, but is actually the Marsaglia polar method.

Comment: Well in literature they just call it the Box-Muller polar form, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform#Polar_form

Answer (score 4):

I am no mathematician, or statistician, but if I think about this I would not expect a Gaussian distribution to return numbers in an exact range. Given your implementation the mean is 0 and the standard deviation is 1 so I would expect values distributed on the bell curve with 0 at the center and then reducing as the numbers deviate from 0 on either side. So the sequence would definitely cover both +/- numbers.

Then since it is statistical, why would it be hard limited to -1..1 just because the std.dev is 1? There can statistically be some play on either side and still fulfill the statistical requirement.

Answer (score 2):

The uniform random variate is indeed within 0..1, but the gaussian random variate (which is what Box-Muller algorithm generates) can be anywhere on the real line.  See [wiki/NormalDistribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I think the function returns polar coordinates. So you need both values to get correct results.

Also, Gaussian distribution is not between `0 .. 1`. It can easily end up as 1000, but probability of such occurrence is extremely low.

Answer (score 0):

This is a monte carlo method so you can't clamp the result, but what you can do is ignore samples.

```
// return random value in the range [0,1].
double gaussian_random()
{
    double sigma = 1.0/8.0; // or whatever works.
    while ( 1 ) {
        double z = gaussian() * sigma + 0.5;
        if (z >= 0.0 && z <= 1.0)
            return z;
    }
}
```