# Code for normal distribution returns unexpected values

Tags: c++, random, normal-distribution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementing Box-Mueller random number generator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817490/implementing-box-mueller-random-number-generator-in-c-sharp)

I'm using a Box-Muller transform method to generate normally distributed random numbers:

```
 do {
        rand1 = 2*(rand()/(double)RAND_MAX)-1 ; 
        rand2 = 2*(rand()/(double)RAND_MAX)-1;
        distSqr = rand1 * rand1 + rand2 * rand2;
  } while (distSqr >= 1 );

  mp1 = sqrt((-2*log(distSqr))/distSqr); 
  res = rand1 * mp1;
  norm_dist=res*var+mean;
```

Is there an obvious mistake that I am making?

Comment: What sort of unexpected values are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting more values outside the variance range and a small number within.