# Compiling with individual Boost libraries, Without installing Boost

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, installation, portability

I'm implementing on some C++ code that I would like to make as portable as possible. I would like to *avoid* dependencies on libraries that require root access to install. Further, I'd prefer to avoid keeping copies of large libraries in my repository, and I would also prefer not to do user-level installations of libraries (simply because I'd have to manually install them on multiple computers.)

I would like to use the `normal_distribution` functionality from Boost in my project. I understand that the typical way to install Boost requires a `sudo apt-get` or `sudo yum` type of command, but I don't have root access on the systems where this code will run. To get around this, I'm wondering if I could simply place a copy of Boost's [normal_distribution.cpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost/random/normal_distribution.html) and [normal_distribution.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_random/reference.html#header.boost.random.normal_distribution_hpp) in my code directory and compile/link my code with these files. Would this work?

Readers may wonder why I'm not just using the `normal_distribution` implementation in TR1 or C++11. The answer is that I need to maintain compatibility with some university-managed clusters that still run g++ 4.1.x, which  (at least in my experience) doesn't support `<TR1/random>`.

Comment: Side note: The project I'm working on is not at all for profit and wouldn't violate any of Boost's license terms.

Comment: boost has a utility to extract the dependencies for any header. it's not completely 100%, but the manual work is greatly reduced. check it out.

Comment: Thanks, Alf. I looked at using BCP (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) for extracting the dependencies--I may still use this. Not sure what the learning curve is like for BCP though, I might see if anything easier comes up before trying BCP.

Comment: Does installing a library require root access?

Comment: You don't need root access, like most libraries you can install boost wherever you like, then simply tell your compiler and linker how to find it.

Comment: I posted a followup question about using BCP here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604285/boost-bcp-doesnt-output-any-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine that [BCP (Boost Copy)](http://www.boost.org/tools/bcp/index.html) was written precisely with your situation in mind.

Comment: All right, I'm trying to set up BCP. I did a `brew install boost` on a Mac OS X machine. I've read that BCP is part of the Boost installation. However. I get `-bash: bcp: command not found` when I type `bcp` on the command line.

Comment: I also did `brew install boost-build`, and I still don't have bcp. When I google bcp, most places say that bcp is part of the boost distribution. Help!

Comment: I got bcp installed. I had to pull the source code from the Boost website and build/install it. Wasn't as tedious as I expected. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should check out the [ryppl](http://www.ryppl.org) project as this is exactly what it is hoping to achieve. If you follow the links to github you will find modularised boost and from there you may go on and try a full ryppl install. In any case there is a half way house and that is [modularised boost](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/CMakeModularizationStatus). There is also a modularised boost/cmake to make it simpler. This is the direction ryppl is looking to take boost and it should be very helpful. The only downside I can see is the propensity to use python scripts for the zero install installer.

As stated BCP was developed for this purpose as well so there is a choice. Be aware though boost is going through a svn->git change and this seems to be affecting some structure which is reflected in some inconsistencies with the current modularised boost, I am not sure how/if that affects BCP as I have no knowledge of that system.

Comment: Interesting. I might pull the current modularized boost / ryppl and install it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble getting BCP to work properly. I documented the [BCP-related question in this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604285/boost-bcp-doesnt-output-any-files).

For the short term, I just added a `normal_distribution` function to my codebase. I put it together from a couple of past StackOverflow posts. This implementation doesn't do any fancy template stuff, but it otherwise looks pretty similar to the Boost, TR1, and C++11 APIs of `normal_distribution`.

```
#include "math.h"
double normal_distribution(double mean, double stdDev)
{
    //scale the number to appropriate distribution 
    return mean + (sampleNormal()*stdDev);
}

//get a number from normal distribution (mean=0, stdDev=1). 
double sampleNormal() {
    double u = ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX)) * 2 - 1;
    double v = ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX)) * 2 - 1;
    double r = u * u + v * v;
    if (r == 0 || r > 1) return sampleNormal(); //recursively re-generate number if doesn't meet criteria
    double c = sqrt(-2 * log(r) / r);
    return u * c;
}
```

Thanks to [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325472/generate-random-numbers-following-a-normal-distribution-in-c-c) (user Pete855217) for the `sampleNormal()` function, and thanks to [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75677/converting-a-uniform-distribution-to-a-normal-distribution) (user5084) for the function that I've named `normal_distribution()`.