# Boost BCP doesn't output any files?

Tags: c++, boost, bcp, normal-distribution

I'm trying to use the [Boost Copy (BCP)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) utility to pull the `normal_distribution` class out of Boost. However, when I do `bcp normal_distribution ./my_normal_distribution_dir`, nothing appears in the my_normal_distribution_dir directory.

Here's some more detailed background on the environment that I'm doing this in:

On Mac OS 10.7, I downloaded the Boost 1.50 and untared source files. In the top-level Boost directory, I did `./bootstrap.sh`. Then, I did `./bjam ./tools/bcp`, which produced a bcp executable in the ./dist/bin directory. I created a directory called my_normal_distribution_dir. Then, I tried the following commands to extract the `normal_distribution` class:

```
./dist/bin/bcp normal_distribution ./my_normal_distribution_dir
./dist/bin/bcp --list normal_distribution --boost=./ ./my_normal_distribution_dir 
./dist/bin/bcp --list normal_distribution --boost=./ output-path:./my_normal_distribution_dir
```

I also tried using the absolute path of my_normal_distribution_dir.

All of these give the following output:

```
no errors detected
```

However, after trying all this stuff, the my_normal_distribution_dir directory is still empty! What should I do?

Also, thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596959/compiling-with-individual-boost-libraries-without-installing-boost) for suggesting BCP. Once we solve the problem described above, BCP should handle my use case perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I never did resolve this. I ended up just manually yanking the files I needed from the Boost codebase. I'd love to learn how to do it the "right" way, though.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like

```
bcp --list math/distributions/normal.hpp
```

Documentation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html#bcp.syntax.module

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but in case anyone else runs across this, I had a similar problem here and I found that bcp was being picky about folders used in names. So while `dist/bin/bcp boost/range/irange mydir` and `dist/bin/bcp irange mydir` didn't work, `dist/bin/bcp range/irange` did. So I'm guessing in the case above,

`./dist/bin/bcp random/normal_distribution ./my_normal_distribution_dir`

might have worked.