# normal_distribution is not a member of std

Tags: c++

Can anyone tell me how I can get rid of this error? It I need to generate normal distribution. But nothing working for me.

I tried to write the code in c++. But showing:

> Error 1   error C2039: 'mt19937' : is not a member of 'std".
>
> normal_distribution is not a member of std

Comment: can you show some code that is producing this error?

Answer (score 3):

Your forgot to include `random`, the header defining the mt19937 ("Mersenne Twister") generator.

Here is a complete example:

```
edd@max:/tmp$ cat cxx12_random.cpp 

// use 'g++ -std=c++0x -o cxx12_random cxx12_random.cpp'

#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  std::mt19937 engine(42);
  std::normal_distribution<> normal(0.0, 1.0);

  for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    std::cout << normal(engine) << std::endl;
  }
}
edd@max:/tmp$ g++ -std=c++0x -o cxx12_random cxx12_random.cpp
edd@max:/tmp$ ./cxx12_random 
-0.550234
0.515433
0.473861
1.36845
-0.916827
edd@max:/tmp$
```

Note that I enabled the newer C++ extensions via `-std=c++0x`. You may have to do the same with your compiler.

Comment: Its showing::Error 1 fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mt19937': No such file or directory c

Comment: Read what I wrote. I did not suggest to a include a file _named_ mt19937, I suggested to include a file _defining_ it.  And I just showed you a *working* example.  You may have problem between your code (which you still didn't show) and your compiler.

Comment: ...................
#include <random>
#include <cmath>
int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
 
    // values near the mean are the most likely
    // standard deviation affects the dispersion of generated values from the mean
    std::normal_distribution<> d(5,2);
 
    std::map<int, int> hist;
    for(int n=0; n<10000; ++n) {
        ++hist[std::round(d(gen))];
    }
    for(auto p : hist) {
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << std::setw(2)
                  << p.first << ' ' << std::string(p.second/200, '*') << '\n';
    }
}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The idea is to *edit your question*, not to ram entire programs into a comment box.

Comment: Dirk one more question.. Is there any way to perform Fourier Transform / inverse Fourier Transform using c++??? I see too many libraries...but I am quite new in c++. So could not make those libraries work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is only available in c++11. does your compiler support it?

Comment: Hi thnx for your reply. I am using Visual Studio 2008

Comment: If im not mistaken 2008 does not support any c++11 features. try it with 2010 or 2012. or use g++..

Comment: is there any other way to generate normal distribution? I need to use the result in OPNET. I am using OPNET modeler 14.5 which doesn't support VS 2010 or newer versions.

Comment: here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325472/generate-random-numbers-following-a-normal-distribution-in-c-c