# Normal random number by averaging 5 uniform samples?

Tags: random, normal-distribution

Looking at some legacy code in our app, found this weird implementation of Normal RNG. I want to swap it for a proper Box-Muller transformation but need some encouragement.

As you can see, it generates 5 random numbers from -3.875 to +3.875 and then averages them out to get a quasi-normally distributed value from -1 to +1. Can this possibly be right? How can this even work? Why 5 samples?

Someone, please explain this:

```
private double GetRandomNormalNumber()
    {
      const double SPREAD = 7.75;
      const double HALFSPREAD = 3.875;
      var random = new Random();

      var fRandomNormalNumber = ((random.NextDouble()*SPREAD - HALFSPREAD) +
                                 (random.NextDouble()*SPREAD - HALFSPREAD) +
                                 (random.NextDouble()*SPREAD - HALFSPREAD) +
                                 (random.NextDouble()*SPREAD - HALFSPREAD) +
                                 (random.NextDouble()*SPREAD - HALFSPREAD)
                                )/5;

      return fRandomNormalNumber;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approximating a normal distribution by averaging several random uniform samples is standard, a consequence of the [Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem). Usually, 12 samples are taken. In your case, someone decided to just take five samples, maybe for the sake of effiency.

Have a look to [Generate random numbers following a normal distribution in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325472/generate-random-numbers-following-a-normal-distribution-in-c-c)

Comment: Thanks, reference to Central Limit Theorem is what I was looking for

Comment: Note that 12 numbers are usually taken not exactly because of CLT, but because variance of a _single_ uniform random variable from [0..1] is 1/12 (as it's E[x^2] - E[x]^2 = 1/3 - 1/4 = 1/12), so sum of 12 such numbers gives variance of 1. So when you add 12 of them and subtract 6, you get a _standard_ normal random variable, with mean=0 and variance=1.

Answer (score 1):

The code seems right, it just causes the area around 0.0 to have higher probability than the edges of the range (-HALFSPREAD, HALFSPREAD).

I doubt the 5 numbers is a well calculated value, most likely it's been chosen "because it works"

If you're replacing one RNG with another you should be able to: as long as the replacement has better practical characteristigs nobody should have relied on a specific output from the existing RNG