# How to add random constant noise in a data?

Tags: noise

I have written a program (based on Mardquart algorithm) to fit a n variable function. For a data without any noise the program is all right. I have used rand() C-library function to add some noise in the data but the distribution of noise is not equally distributed as a result fitting is bad.

Can any one tell me how to add noise with regular distribution around a data?

Answer (score 0):

You need a PRNG that produces a normal, Gaussian, or other distribution. If you can't get your hands on one, you can do the mapping on your own. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325472/generate-random-numbers-following-a-normal-distribution-in-c-c) seems to answer how to do that. Either way, add that normally distributed number (multiplied by a standard deviation of your choosing) to the y value of your samples.

Comment: Wait, I got ahead of myself. What do you want a regular distribution for noise?