# generation of random number with normal distribution in specific range(for example [0,1]) in C programming

Tags: c, random, normal-distribution

I know that how to generate random number with normal distribution,
but my problem is determining range of numbers are produced.
I need these numbers for random electrons velocities(dimensionless) which are between zero and one.

Comment: I just googled this for you:  [Generate random numbers following a normal distribution in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325472/generate-random-numbers-following-a-normal-distribution-in-c-c).

Comment: Actually, what do you mean "normal distribution in specific **range**?!" Normal distribution... "normally" has **infinite *range***

Comment: "random number with normal distribution in specific range" There is no such thing. It's either normal or in a specific range.

Comment: I know Box-Muller transform method, Do you mean to specify the range by specifying the mean and standard deviation?