# What is the best way to generate normally distributed random numbers in C?

Tags: c, random, gaussian, normal-distribution

I need to use normally distributed random numbers in my program. Let's say I need to generate x (size is R^(m x n) )  whose elements are from the Gaussian distribution of zero mean and one variance. How do I do this in C with good accuracy?

Comment: [This answer provides C code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23609868/211160), FWIW.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/lib/gaussian.html

Comment: [Box-Muller Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box–Muller_transform) is a common way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of algorithms to produce a normal distribution if you have a uniform random generator. Have a look at [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Generating_values_from_normal_distribution) of the wikipedia article. One possible approach is by using the [central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem). The approach here would be to generate many integer values with uniform distribution and then compute their arithmetic mean.

Comment: The most practical approach? It takes a dozen uniform samples to get a single variable that's at least roughly normal distributed, and far more to get better approximations. It's not like the Box-Muller method is particularly complicated. It only needs square root, logarithm, and trigonometry - i.e. `libm`. Probably not even more lines of code.

Comment: @delnan actually I did not read all the suggested ideas. I have simply done something similar with central limit theorem. I will re-phrase the answer.