# tr1/normal_distribution: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, tr1

I'm trying to use TR1 for some C++ project. Unfortunately I get an error and don't understand why or how I should do it correctly!
I'm working under Linux with gcc 4.4.5.

I get the error

```
myfile.cpp:21:35: error: tr1/normal_distribution: No such file or directory
```

The TR1 file I need is imported via:

```
#include <tr1/normal_distribution>
```

in CMakeLists.txt I turn on TR1 support (-std=c++0x)

```
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -std=c++0x -DNDEBUG -O3 -march=nocona -msse4.2")
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118482/c-tr1-how-to-use-the-normal-distribution

Comment: The header is `tr1/random`. Also for TR1 with gcc you don't need C++0x support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The flag `-std=c++0x` gives you access to whatever c++11 functionality is implemented in your version of gcc. For random number distributions, c++11 has the header `random`. You do not need the `tr1` namespace when using c++11.

The `tr1` version of random is in include `tr1/random`, and everything there is under the `std::tr1` namespace. To access this you do not need the `c++0x` flag.

To be clear:

For TR1 random numbers: `#include <tr1/random>` and use `std::tr1::normal_distribution`.

For c++11 random numbers: compile with flag `c++0x`, then `#include <random>` and use `std::normal_distribution`.

Comment: Apparantly I need it. If I don't, I get the following error:

/usr/include/c++/4.4/c++0x_warning.h:31:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.

Comment: I don't use normal random numbers but a normal_distribution

Comment: @MichaelGg that is strange. Are you including <random> (c++11) or <tr1/random>?

Comment: @MichaelGg the `normal_distribution` is defined in <tr1/random> and <random>, the latter needs C++11 support, the former not.

Comment: #include <random>

But in there there is some TR1 stuff it seems, such as:
#if defined(_GLIBCXX_INCLUDE_AS_CXX0X)
#  include <tr1_impl/random>
#else

Comment: @MichaelGg I updated my answer to spell it out. TR1 shouldn't need C++11 support. C++11 obviously does :-)

Comment: @MichaelGg it depends, I use C++11 a lot, but if you want your code to be portable to compilers that don't support it, then you are better off with TR1, at least for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

I believe its `#include <random>`. Anyway, check that.

Answer (score 0):

try to add the following flags to cxx on CMakeLists.txt:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-stdlib=libstdc++")
```

`-std=c++0x` is not necessary