# Producing random float from negative to positive range?

Tags: c++, random, range

I am trying to produce a random float within the range -50.0 and 50.0 inclusively, using rand(). I've looked everywhere for an answer but it deals with ints and % operator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ random float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686353/c-random-float)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
float RandomNumber(float Min, float Max)
{
    return ((float(rand()) / float(RAND_MAX)) * (Max - Min)) + Min;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

1. `rand()` gives you a number between 0 and `RAND_MAX`
2. so divide by `RAND_MAX` to get a number between 0 and 1
3. you desire a range of 100 from -50 to 50, so multiply by 100.0
4. finally shift the center from 50 (between 0 and 100 per point 3) to zero by subtracting 50.0

Answer (score 4):

```
((float)rand())/RAND_MAX * 100.0 - 50.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, all present answers don't explain that there is a change in distribution in their solutions(I am assuming that rand() follows the uniform distribution! correct me if I am wrong please). Use a library please, and my recommendation is using the new facilities in C++0x:

```
#include <random>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 generator;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> uniform_distribution(-50.0, 50.0);
    auto my_rand = std::bind(uniform_distribution, generator);
}
```

If you can't, Boost is a perfect choice. That way, you can use my_rand() just like good ol' rand():

```
std::vector<float> random_numbers(1000);
std::generate(random_numbers.begin(), random_numbers.end(), my_rand);
```

Comment: The question says he needs to use `rand` specifically.  But yes, I agree; if distribution is really important then boost seems like a good option.

Comment: @Max: More precisely, the question says "trying...using rand()"; the OP never said it was a *requirement*.

Comment: @Jefromi Good point.  I must be more sleep-deprived than usual.  :P