# Generate random float between two floats

Tags: c++, random

I know this is a rather simple question, but I'm just not too good at maths.

I know how to generate a random float between 0 and 1:

```
float random = ((float) rand()) / (float) RAND_MAX;
```

- But what, if I want a function that given a range of two floats, returns a pseudorandom float in that range?

Example:

```
RandomFloat( 0.78, 4.5 ); //Could return 2.4124, 0.99, 4.1, etc.
```

Comment: Also, if you can, prefer double over float.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ random float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686353/c-random-float)

Comment: Starting with C++11, you should no longer generate random numbers this way. Use the safer and more convenient [random](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) module instead.

Answer (score 38):

```
float RandomFloat(float a, float b) {
    float random = ((float) rand()) / (float) RAND_MAX;
    float diff = b - a;
    float r = random * diff;
    return a + r;
}
```

This works by returning `a` plus *something*, where *something* is between 0 and `b-a` which makes the end result lie in between `a` and `b`.

Comment: @stefan Nope, you don't. If you do add the `fabsf`, then you need to change the last line as well to `min(a,b) + r`.

Comment: The way it's written now, if `b < a`, then `diff < 0` and `a + r` will be `< a`.

Comment: You are right, it's just confusing that 1.0 will make the lower value ;)

Comment: this "random" number still has granularity proportional to the number of integers in the range 0-RAND_MAX.  How do you get an actual random float?

Comment: RAND_MAX is usually 2^31 so it provides more random bits than there are bits in the mantissa of a float. For doubles you can use drand48() which provides a double value between 0.0 and 1.0 (which you would use instead of `random` above), it has 48 random bits which is closer to (but still fewer than) the mantissa bits in a double (52).

Comment: just to note, in 2018, this code violates gcc's "old style cast" flag. Need to use `static_cast<float>(RAND_MAX)`

Comment: Another note: Starting with C++11, you should no longer generate random numbers this way. Use the safer and more convenient [random](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) module instead.

Answer (score 7):

```
float RandomFloat(float min, float max)
{
    // this  function assumes max > min, you may want 
    // more robust error checking for a non-debug build
    assert(max > min); 
    float random = ((float) rand()) / (float) RAND_MAX;

    // generate (in your case) a float between 0 and (4.5-.78)
    // then add .78, giving you a float between .78 and 4.5
    float range = max - min;  
    return (random*range) + min;
}
```

Comment: @stefan, yes you're correct. I missed how random was calculated and was scaling it from 0-RAND_MAX back down. Looks like I needed to scale it back up.

Comment: missing ; in last statement

Comment: Note: Starting with C++11, you should no longer generate random numbers this way. Use the safer and more convenient [random](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) module instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Random between 2 float :**

```
float    random_between_two_int(float min, float max)    
{    
    return (min + 1) + (((float) rand()) / (float) RAND_MAX) * (max - (min + 1));    
}
```

**Random between 2 int :**

```
int    random_between_two_int(float min, float max)    
{    
    return rand() % (max - min) + min + 1;     
}
```

Comment: `-1` because considering that C++ standard library has way better pseudorandom generation, this answer doesn't add anything valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, you have MIN_RAND and MAX_RAND defining the ranges, then you can have the following:

```
const float MIN_RAND = 2.0, MAX_RAND = 6.0;
const float range = MAX_RAND - MIN_RAND;
float random = range * ((((float) rand()) / (float) RAND_MAX)) + MIN_RAND ;
```

This will provide you the number scaled to your preferred range.
MIN_RAND, MAX_RAND can be any value, like say 2.5, 6.6
So, the function could be as:

```
float RandomFloat(float min, float max) {
    return  (max - min) * ((((float) rand()) / (float) RAND_MAX)) + min ;
}
```

Comment: Use c++11 random generators instead.