# generating a random value between 0.001 and 0.0015

Tags: matlab, random

I want to generate random values between 0.001 and 0.0015 such that each time I run a for loop, i get a new value.

e.g

```
value = random number between 0.001 and 0.0015;
for i = 1:10,
   for value,
         Calculate something...
   end
end
```

Can any one tell me how to do that?

Comment: Take a loot at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5289624/252591 - it's C++ but porting it to MatLab should be easy task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's all written in the documentation of `rand()` function: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html

> Example 1 Generate values from the uniform distribution on the
>   interval [a, b]:

```
 r = a + (b-a).*rand(100,1);
```

So in your case `a = 0.001` and `b = 0.0015` and you can also change `rand(100,1)` to just `rand(10,1)` to give you `10` random values on the interval `[a,b]`.

Comment: Actually he only needs one per time, so he will need 10 in total.

Comment: It's a quote from the documentation. I think everyone should be able to adapt this solution to 10 values...

Answer (score 4):

It's simple, you just do:

```
 0.001+(rand()*(0.0015-0.001))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you should be doing it in my opinion:

```
myNumbers = rand(10,1)*0.0005+0.001;
for value = myNumbers;
   %Calculate something
   value
end
```

Note that the main improvement here is that you precalculate all random values at once.

Furthermore you can loop over them directly.

Comment: `0.0015-0.001=0.0005` not `0.014` :)