# true or false based on probability

Tags: c++

i'm getting a bit confused with operators and there use with random generation. I guess i'm just asking does this code do what I want it to?

Generate a 'random' `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on what probability I assigned the function.

```
bool randtf(int probability) {
    if ((rand() % 100) < probability)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

so if `randtf(63)` it has a 63% chance of being `TRUE`?

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where does rand() come from? Does it return a random float between 0 and 1 (exclusive)?

Comment: @dgrant, if it returned a float, `% 100` would give you a compiler error.

Comment: At the moment no, its just the standard shitty rand(), I used this for  the question.

Comment: @dgrant: I think we can assume that unless qualified otherwise, this is the standard library `rand()`.

Comment: stylistically, don't `return true` or `return false` like that.  Just `return (rand() % 100) < probability;`  May as well cut out the redundancy...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, to a first approximation.

No, more accurately.  `rand()` returns a number between `0` and `RAND_MAX`, which in practice will always be of the form `(1 << n) - 1`.  This isn't a multiple of 100, so you won't get a perfectly uniform distribution when you take the modulo.

You can fix that by using rejection sampling.  For the sake of argument, let's assume `RAND_MAX == 32767` (i.e. 16-bit).  The first step is to keep generating random numbers, rejecting them until you obtain one less than 32700 (the largest multiple of 100 that's less than `RAND_MAX`).  If you then do the modulo trick on that, you will get a uniform distribution.

Of course, this assumes a sane, statistically robust, implementation of `rand()`, which is quite an assumption!

Comment: If RAND_MAX is 32767 The bottom 0-27 will be slightly more likely than 28-99 by ~3.125%

Comment: Not with C++03 standard library.  Can be done with http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/random/random-distributions.html.  Unsure about C++11, the draft had a better RNG, but I haven't verified that made it to the final.

Comment: @Elgoog see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887941/random-number-from-9-to-9-in-c/7888357#7888357) or directly [the man page of rand](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand) (The Notes section)

Answer (score 0):

MAX_RAND is not a multiple of 100, so your distribution would technically not be fair.  You have to scale rand(), not mod it.

Comment: why because rand() is not very random in the first place?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, by scale I assume he means `(float)rand()/RAND_MAX < prob / 100.0`, what would be wrong with that?

Comment: @mikerobi: Because `rand` returns an integer.  There is not a perfect n-to-1 mapping between the input domain [0,RAND_MAX] and the output domain [0,99].  (Consider a simpler case where RAND_MAX was 7, and you wanted a random number between 0 and 2, inclusive).

Comment: ok, smart-*$$.... so the monster will show up a billisecond too soon on average. :)

Comment: @MartyTPS: This is exactly as non-uniform as the mod version; they fail for the same reason.

Comment: ok, so scale your input parameter and just use rand() as is.  You get closer.

Comment: @Marty: You don't.  Fundamentally, you are trying to map (e.g.) 32768 things onto 100 things, and that just doesn't divide up equally.

Comment: @Marty: for 32767->100 mapping, some appear over 3% more often. 3% might (or mght not) be too much for whatever it is doing.  He's implied he wants better

Comment: No I just suggested a 100->32767 mapping of the input instead.

Comment: Regardless of how accurately you can divide up the range we still have the problem that rand() is just a good enough for games random number.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what `rand()` returns, and in particular if the range of possible numbers is a an exact multiple of 100 (and uniformly distributed). In general, using modulo does not necessarily give you the correct statistical behaviour.

For example's sake, suppose your `rand()` only returned the valued 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6; and you said `rand() % 5 < p` (where `0 <= p < 5`). But behold: This takes the values 0 and 1 twice, but 2, 3 and 4 only once across the range of valid source numbers! So with `p = 4` you *don't* actually get 80% probability, but only 1/7.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the random generator is perfectly random, because `rand()` only generates numbers from 0 to 0x7FFF, it cannot be perfectly distributed. consider the following code:

```
int arr[100] = { 0 };
for( int i=0; i<0x7FFF; i++ ){
arr[ i % 100 ]++;
}

for( int i=0; i<100; i++ ){
    cout << arr[i] << endl;
}
return 0;
```

If you run this code, it's not going to give you the same number:

```
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
328
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
327
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: `rand()` doesn't generate numbers "from 0 to 0x7fff", but "from 0 to RAND_MAX", that on many common platform is way bigger than 0x7fff. I agree on the rest, though.

Comment: Wow that's a long post on my itty bitty cell phone :P