# Random double between min and max

Tags: c++, random

```
double get_random(double min, double max) {
  /* Returns a random double between min and max */

  return min * ((double) rand() / (double) RAND_MAX) - max;
}
```

That's my function to generate random doubles between a min and a max. However, when I call `get_random(-1.0, 1.0);`, I get values between -2.0 and -1.0.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: (rand/RAND_MAX) generates a number between 0.0 and 1.0.  So put those two extremes into the rest of the equation, and you should see why it doesn't work.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686353/c-random-float

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Shouldn't the formula be

```
(max - min) * ( (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX ) + min
```

- `(double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX` returns a random number between `0` and `1`
- `(max - min) * ( (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX )` returns a random number between `0` and `max - min`.
- the whole expression will return a random number between `0 + min` and `min + (max-min)` - i.e. `min` and `max`.

Comment: Just as a warning: this method will probably generate a small fraction, well under 1%, of possible random numbers in your selected range.  Use `<random>` (if available) for higher-quality random doubles.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for generating random double or floating numbers:

```
((double) rand()*(max-min)/(double)RAND_MAX-min);
```

Comment: Is there any specific advantage of this compared to the accepted answer? Could you explain more?

Comment: I agree with @jogojapan, and the final `-min` is the only difference from the accepted answer of `+min` (as far as I can see), thus this answer is wrong.