# C++ Random Number Generator does not generate numbers correctly at all

Tags: c++, random

This is my function:

```
Random(int min, int max)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    return (rand() % (max-min)) + 1;
    // or
    return (rand() % (max+min)) + 1;
    // or
    return (rand() % (max-min))
    // or
    return (rand() % (max+min))
};
```

And it isn't working, if I say add Random(5, 10) it sometimes show up 15, 5, 4. I can't figure it out, because all guides say "this is the way it's suppose to be" but it doesn't work. What have I missed?

This methos is part of a class.

I've tried srand(time(NULL)) placed in:

1. Not at all
2. In constructor
3. In method

No results.

Shouldn't rand() return a value between 0 and 1? Mine doesn't.

Comment: You should "figure out" how functions work by reading the documentation and *thinking* about the code you write, instead of trying every permutation of the relevant tokens in your code.

Comment: Related, please read. http://stackoverflow.com/a/686373/241536

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Call `srand` only once
2. Use `return (rand() % (max-min+1)) + min`;
   (+1 is for including `max` into range)
3. `rand()` returns a value between 0 and `RAND_MAX` and is a positive integer.

Comment: @Deukalion: You can learn all of this and much more from the fine documentation, e.g. the [manual page of `rand`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand) in section 3.

Comment: Thank you. I tried every example and it didn't work at all. I have been using these functions since forever, never tried understanding enough but I understand the principle. And I just forgot about minimum. Sorry, about this mess :P

Answer (score 3):

> man rand(3)

function signature is `int rand(void);` So it already can't return a value between 0 and 1 since its an integral.

**Return values:**
The rand() and rand_r() functions return a value between 0 and RAND_MAX (inclusive). The srand() function returns no value.

from [man rand(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand)