# i m trying to generate random number but every time i am getting error ‘ranf’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, random, numbers, generator

here is the code which is giving error 'ranf' was not declared in this scope.
 the code is about generating random numbers with initial position and velocity.
i am not able to configure how to resolve the problem.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cmath>
#include<ctime>
#include<map>
using namespace std;

const int N= 3000, nstep= 20000000, nps= 50000, nprint =1000, noverlap= 10000;
const double R=1, eps=0.95, Lbox=150,pssize= 500;
const double infty= 1e20, null= 1e-10;

vector<double> x(N), y(N), vx(N), vy(N);
vector<double> clist[N];
double Time = 0;
map<double, pair<int,int> > cseq;

void init(double tol)
{
bool overlap;
int i, j;
x[0]= ranf(Lbox-R-tol);
y[0]= ranf(Lbox-R-tol);
vx[0]=ranf(1);
vy[0]=ranf(1);

for(i=1;i<N;i++)
 {
   if(!(1 % 100)) cout << "Init " << i << endl;
  do {
   overlap = false;
  x[i]= ranf(Lbox-R-tol);
  y[i]= ranf(Lbox-R-tol); 
  j=0;
   do {
   overlap = ((x[i]-x[j])*(x[i]-x[j])+ (y[i]-y[j])*(y[i]-y[j]) < 4*(R+tol)*(R+tol));
  }
  while((++j<i) && !overlap);
 }
 while(overlap);
 vx[i]=ranf(1);`enter code here`
vy(i)=ranf(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `rand`? AFAIR there is no `ranf` functino in the C-libraries you use.

Comment: PS: maybe you want to improve your code indentation - this random-jumpy indentation style is worse than no indentation at all ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ranf` function you are calling is not standardized in any way I'm aware of, so it's undefined because it simply does not exist. You need to define it first. Something like this should work:

```
double ranf(double max)
{
  return (((double)rand())/RAND_MAX)*max;
}
```

Comment: I wonder if `(RAND_MAX + 1.0)` is preferable. This would return a double in the semi-open range [0.0, 1.0).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you got the right function? It is actually `rand` defined in `cstdlib`. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) for a reference.

Comment: Since he's calling it with a parameter, and expecting a `double` result, I'm assuming topicstarter used it before from some other non-standarized library, not just confusing the name.

Comment: @Niels This might be possible. But you should refrain from not-standard functions for sake of portability.

Comment: That's why I supplied a local implementation in my answer based on stdlib  :)

Answer (score 0):

The function `ranf` seems designed to return a random floating point in the (0, x) range.

You can check out [C++ random float number generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686353/c-random-float) and roll out your own `ranf`:

```
/**
 * ranf - return a random double in the [0,m] range.
 * @param m      maximum value to be returned
 * @return       a random double in the [0,m] range
 */
double ranf(double m) {
    return (m*rand())/(double)RAND_MAX;
}
```

or also

```
#define ranf(m)   (((m)*rand())/(double)RAND_MAX)
```

Remember to call `srand` to initialize the random number generator, or each run of your program will always return the same sequence of "random" numbers. (which can be useful for debugging, though).