# How do I get a random number from 0 to 1700 in a string?

Tags: c++

currently I'm working with

```
double fRand(double fMin, double fMax)
{
    double f = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    return fMin + f * (fMax - fMin);
}

double RangeFinder::getRange(void) {
  return fRand(0, 1700);
};


char range[12];
double r = rangeFinder.getRange();
snprintf(range, 11, "range: %d", r);
```

But it isn't giving me between `0`,`1700` its giving me between `-99`,`999` ( I think ).  I have a feeling the msb is interpretting the thousands place as negative.

What's the fix?

---

## Edit

#### fixed version

```
double fRand(double fMin, double fMax)
{
    double f = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    return fMin + f * (fMax - fMin);
}

double RangeFinder::getRange(void) {
  return fRand(0, 1700);
};



char range[22];
int r = rangeFinder.getRange();
snprintf(range, 22, "range: %i    ", r);
LCDString(range);
```

the 2nd arg to `snprintf` was 11.. too short.  there weren't white characters after the number to clear out previous values, and the `double r` needed to be cast `int r`.

Comment: Keep running it. *Sure* it is in the reported [-99,999] range? I doubt it. Trivially, with reduction of the supplied values: `return f * 1700`, where `0.0 <= f <= 1.0` due to `(double)rand()/RAND_MAX`.

Comment: Consider that `%d` is questionable in this case, as `r` is typed as a `double`. Try to cast `r` while supplying it to `snprintf`, use a different format specifier, and/or return `int` from getRange.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: No, it's not a duplicate of that question. The OP's logic in `fRand` is correct; the problem is the use of a `"%d"` format string for a `double` argument.

Comment: @user2864740 you were right.  Just using `%f` or `%lf` in the string gave me `?` instead of a number, but casting it as `int` instead of `double` and changing `%d` to `%i` worked.  Also, i had to add spaces afterwards to clear out the numbers staying on the lcd

Comment: See second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686353/c-random-float-number-generation. Note that it is now part of standard library.

Comment: i can't use standard lib as this is going to a microcontroller atmega

Answer (score 5):

A possible problem is that the `"%d"` is used for integers. In order to print float/doubles you should use `"%f"`(floats) or `"%lf"`(doubles or long float).

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. Except that `"%f"` is for both `float` and `double` (because `float` arguments are promoted to `double` for variadic functions), and `"%Lf"` is for `long double`. `"%lf"` is equivalent to `"%f"`. (There is no `long float`.)

Answer (score 3):

A word of caution: Stephan T. Lavavej, in his presentation [rand() Considered Harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful), made a strong point on why not to use `rand()` in C++ and showcased the c++11 alternatives.

Your fRand could be written as

```
#include <random>

double fRand(double fMin, double fMax)
{
    std::random_device rd;

    std::mt19937 e2(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist(fMin, fMax);

    return dist(e2);
}
```

The additional gain here (besides using a robust and correct proven piece of code) is that

1. std::uniform_real_distribution produces random floating-point values i, uniformly distributed on the interval [fMin, fMax), so you won't be introducing any bias in your randomness.
2. Your are producing directly random floating-point values and not integers which are then cast to double.

Comment: well thanks for the insight, but in production, the random data will be real data, so I'm not too worried about it.

Comment: Also be sure to truncute your floating point number inside the sprintf as so "%.nlf" where n is the number of digits you want to use and the size of the char array, or else you're overflow it

Comment: Also use [sprintf_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx) as sprintf is not safe (modern compilers will complain about its usage)