# Generate random number between 0 and 1

Tags: c++, random, numbers, generator

Simple question but difficult to me. I want to generate uniformly distributed random numbers between `0 and 1`, how can I do it? In matlab I am using rand, in *C++* `rand()` returns integers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ random float number generation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686353/c-random-float-number-generation)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since C++11, use [`std::uniform_real_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution)

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use the RAND_MAX constant to divide the randomly generated integer

Comment: Remember to cast it to a double/float! `rand() / (float)RAND_MAX`

Comment: ah very fast catch :) saved my answer from being useless

Comment: It's common to need numbers that are in the range `[0,1)` rather than `[0,1]`, in which case divide by `(RAND_MAX+1.0)`.

Comment: @pjs RAND_MAX can be equal to MAX_INT so it can cause overflow and you will get MAX_INT+1 = -MAX_INT which will cause to generate random number in the range (-1,0]

Comment: @pio note that I said `+1.0`, not `+1`.

Comment: @pjs ohh, so you mean that it will be converted to float, and we can be sure that MAX_FLOAT > RAND_MAX . nice :)

Comment: @pio The conversion to float is necessary anyway to get uniforms between 0 and 1, so that seems like a reasonable place to kick accomplish it in C++.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how random you need the numbers to be.  Generally, if I don't care about how random it is I will just use rand and divide by MAX_RAND (I bet matlab's rand is better than c's rand).

However, most of what I have done has required a better random number generator than the c function rand, and I don't need it to be cryptographically secure.  In this case I use a mersenne twister   class (http://www.bedaux.net/mtrand/) which has seemed to work better for the simulated annealing and monte carlo simulations that I sometimes find myself doing.

Also with this class, there is a way to get a random int32 and a radom double (between 0 and 1) out.