# random unit vector in 2 dimension

Tags: c++, random, vector

I wanted to generate a uniformly random unit vector in 2 dimensions and I have been using the following snippet in C++

```
double ranf(double x)
{
    return double(rand()) * x / (double(RAND_MAX));
}

double phi = ranf(2 * M_PI);

double ndx = cos(phi);
double ndy = sin(phi);
```

Is this correct?

Comment: You're basically asking how to generate a floating-point number between 0 and `x`. This question probably contains your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686353/c-random-float-number-generation

Answer (score 2):

You're generating a random angle `phi` uniformly between 0 and 2Pi, which is the "heading" of your vector. By using unscaled `sin` and `cos`, you're implicitly assuming that the length of the vector is 1 and decomposing it into its vertical and horizontal components.  Looks basically correct to me.

A couple of minor details: 1) When you divide by `RAND_MAX` rather than `RAND_MAX+1`, you're allowing both zero and x to occur, in your case both 0 and 2Pi, and those two values are the same in angular terms.  You may want to change the divisor accordingly.  2) I'd recommend multiplying by `2.0` rather than `2` to avoid the implicit up-conversion when you multiply it by `M_PI`, but this is probably taken care of by your compiler anyway.

There's another way to do this which generalizes to an arbitrary number of dimensions: Generate k-tuples (z<sub>1</sub>, z<sub>2</sub>,..., z<sub>k</sub>) where each of the z's has a normal distribution.  Calculate the norm N=sqrt(z<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + z<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> + ... + z<sub>k</sub><sup>2</sup>), and use it to create a normalized vector X=(z<sub>1</sub>/N, z<sub>2</sub>/N,..., z<sub>k</sub>/N). The result is that X has unit length (because of the normalization) and its direction is uniformly distributed over the k-dimensional unit hypersphere thanks to the distributional properties of the normals.

Comment: note, if `RAND_MAX` is the maximum value of its type then dividing by `RAND_MAX+1` will be problematic - be careful to write `(RAND_MAX + 1.0)` or similar

Comment: @MattMcNabb Good observation. In reality, I'd recommend avoiding `rand()` completely in favor of BOOST's `uniform_01` backed by mt19937 or one of the lagged fibonacci generators.