# Random number between (0,2) uniformly distributed

Tags: c++, random

I want to generate random numbers between `(0,2)`. I am using the following code:

```
double fRand(double fMin, double fMax)
{
  double f = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
  return fMin + f * (fMax - fMin);
}
```

and setting:

```
fMin = 0; fMax = 2;
```

But I am not getting uniformly distributed numbers. I call this function in a loop.

It generates random numbers, but almost all the numbers are falling in two regions only, not uniformly distributed.

How do I make sure the numbers are uniformly distributed?

Comment: As far as I can tell this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/686353/1708801) covers what you are looking for in both C++11 and pre C++11. If you can use C++11 then just use the `random` header. [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17798317/1708801) to the question provides solutions in C++11, Boost and using `rand`.

Comment: Did you call `srand()`?

Comment: @Cornstalks calling `srand` or not will almost not change the distribution for large n.

Comment: No i am using C++ only but i am not calling any srand,,i m just calling fRand(0,2),,where fRand is defined above

Comment: can you make a plot? in my opinion it should be uniform distributed. at least some sort of ... you should get RAND_MAX distinct values between fMin and fMax.

Comment: for(i=0;i<10;i++)
i want to genrate point (x1,y1) in the range {0,2} and from (x1,y1) & (1,1) as center calculate slope. FInd the normal from (x1,y1) and draw the normal.All these normals plot on the plate with dimensions {0,2} center as (1,1). And finally the normals shld not fall in a particular region they shld be uniformly distributed.

Comment: Did the duplicate answer your question? If not can you clarify why not?

Comment: My question is with the above i can generate random points and if u pot x Vs Y u can fills some spaces and u can also abserve some points concentrate on a particular are,,,,which i dont want...

Comment: @GaneshDelli sounds like a poor quality random number generator if I understand you correctly. The proper fix would be to the `random` header which should provide solid algorithm. This is one of the main drives for the push to depreciate `rand`. If you have to use `rand` then the [C-FAQ link](http://c-faq.com/lib/rand48.html) I include in my answer may help, there may be other SO questions that deal with how to get better quality from `rand` but I would have to look later on.

Comment: That wouldn't explain *that* bad a distribution. OP, did you try just casting RAND_MAX to double as well? ie. `double f = (double)rand() / (double) RAND_MAX;`

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do this.

you could use rand, but your results will be slightly biased.

What `rand()` does:

```
Returns a pseudo-random integral number in the range between 0 and RAND_MAX.
```

Example:

```
RandomFunction = rand() % 100;      // declares a random number between 0-99

RandomFunction2 = rand() % 100 + 1; // declares a random number between 1-100

This is in the library #include <cstdlib>
```

You can also set the seed with

```
srand()
```

What this does is set the value of the random numbers, which will be same if the function is repeated with the same value for `srand()`. This is sometimes preferred in debugging, as it makes the result clear.

Reference: [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/)

Also here's the function for finding unbiased values,

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 10);


//This function creates a random number between 1-10 and is stored in dis(gen).
// You can change the name of dis if you like.
```

Example:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 6);

    for (int n=0; n<10; ++n)
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

This will generate `10` random numbers between `1-6`. Example Reference: [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

Comment: that does no explain whats wrong with the OPs approach.

Comment: I'm suggesting an alternative approach.

Comment: OP wants floating point numbers between 0 and 2. This is not actually a suitable alternative.

Comment: Note, the community in general feels [cppreference is a better reference than cplusplus.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194788/213111)