# How to implement a os.urandom function - Python2

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, binary

I'm implementing a function in order to replace `os.urandom(n)`. The code below is what I have so far:

```
def random_entropy(n):
    """
    Returns a random entropy, which is a sequence of numbers between 0, 255

    :n: a integer number
    """
    if n <= 0:
        return ""
    buffer = []
    for i in range(0, n):
        number = random.randint(0, 255)
        buffer.append(hex(number))
    
    return ''.join(buffer)
```

if I go to the terminal, I get the following output:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.urandom(10)
'm\xd4\x94\x00x7\xbe\x04\xa2R'
>>> type(os.urandom(10))
<type 'str'>
>>> map(ord, os.urandom(10))
[65, 120, 218, 135, 66, 134, 141, 140, 178, 25]
```

in the end, I want my function to return a similar output as `os.urandom`: `'m\xd4\x94\x00x7\xbe\x04\xa2R'` (I mean, the binary output). How can I achieve that? I'm implementing this for an ecdsa module for SGX, so I can't use the `os` or `secrets` packages.

From the Python documentation:

> Return a string of size random bytes suitable for cryptographic use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does secrets module do to make perfect random sequences in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65311182/what-does-secrets-module-do-to-make-perfect-random-sequences-in-python)

Comment: You're using Python 2 aren't you?

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm... I will update the question

Comment: You may want to read [Whats the difference between os.urandom() and random?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47514695/5987) - you can't substitute `random` for `urandom`.

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm implementing a SGX module for ecdsa, but it relies on `os.urandom` for entropy. However, we can't use `os` in SGX, that's why I have to implement this module. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: @PeterO. it does not ... `secrets` is not a library in SGX, so it can't be used.

Comment: I highlighted that question because its answer shows how cryptographic generators generally work: they ultimately rely on nondeterministic sources which are hard to guess.  Another relevant question is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62375129/how-to-get-truly-random-data-not-random-data-fed-into-a-prng-seed-like-csrngs  And in any case, the `random` module (except for `random.SystemRandom`, which may or may not work for you) is not a cryptographic generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, before you embark on this you should know that `random` is not an adequate substitute for `urandom` in many applications.  Read the links given in the question comments.  You're abusing the word "entropy" in the name of your function.

By using `hex` on each of your numbers, you're converting it to a readable multi-character string representation.  You don't want that, you want `chr` instead.

Here's a quick fix of your code for Python 2:

```
def random_entropy(n):
    """
    Returns a random entropy, which is a sequence of numbers between 0, 255

    :n: a integer number
    """
    if n <= 0:
        return ""
    buffer = []
    for i in range(0, n):
        number = random.randint(0, 255)
        buffer.append(chr(number))
    
    return ''.join(buffer)
```

There's no need to generate a list first, you can put a loop directly into the `join` and simplify things greatly:

```
def random_entropy(n):
    """
    Returns a random entropy, which is a sequence of numbers between 0, 255

    :n: a integer number
    """
    return ''.join(chr(random.randint(0, 255)) for _ in range(n))
```

Python 3 does things a little differently.  Here's the equivalent:

```
def random_entropy(n):
    """
    Returns a random entropy, which is a sequence of numbers between 0, 255

    :n: a integer number
    """
    return b''.join(random.randint(0, 255).to_bytes(1, 'little') for _ in range(n))
```

Edit: finally in Python 3.9 there is a function in `random` that delivers exactly what you ask: [`random.randbytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randbytes). Note the warning given there:

> This method should not be used for generating security tokens. Use
> [secrets.token_bytes()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.token_bytes) instead.

```
def random_bytes(n):
    """
    Returns a random byte string, which is a sequence of numbers between 0, 255.
    This should not be used in any application requiring cryptographic security.

    :n: a integer number for the number of bytes requested.
    """
    return random.randbytes(n)
```