# how to generate random numbers between [0,1] using thread on POSIX

Tags: c, multithreading, random, posix

I want to generate million of random numbers between 0 and 1 (0 and 1 included) using thread on POSIX. I try two codes but it still give me wrong results, it generate large signed numbers.

code(1):

```
srand(time(NULL));
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   double r = (double)(rand()%1001)/1000;
  printf("Random double, 0 to 1: %f\n",r);
}
```

code(2):

```
srand(time(NULL));
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   double r = rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
   printf("Random double, 0 to 1: %f\n",r);
}
```

The results generated are like these:

12451421454

-4514251445

96541213212

-56543214521

SO what is the solution ,,,, please

Comment: The solution starts by telling us how a POSIX thread has *anything* to do with what little code you actually posted, followed shortly thereafter by posting a *real* [**MVCE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Looks fine here: http://ideone.com/23uQAG

Comment: `printf("PI = %d\n",pi);`  the `%d` format specifier prints  one integer. Could you try to use `%f` or `%g` instead ?

Comment: the problem begin before printf("PI = %d\n",pi); ,,, the values of x and y are NOT random numbers between 0 and 1

Comment: They are. The code you **show** to generate x and y works as intended, and does not show the (integer) results you claim. Your error lies somewhere else--and it's *very* probable it's not even an actual error but you only used the wrong `printf` format somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right ! The computed value of pi is not precise.

If you have 30 min, look at this [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) about generation of random number. Or this question [C++ random float number generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686353/c-random-float-number-generation).

`x=(double)(rand()%1001)/1000;` is not the right way to generate random numbers between 0 and 1...There are only 1000 possible values and some are more probable than others since `RAND_MAX%1001!=0`! `x = rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;` works better.

Moreover, remember the central limit theorem : the error goes like `1/sqrt(total)` : you will never get 10 digits. Try to increase `total`.

And `sqrt(x*x+y*y)<1` is costly : `(x*x+y*y)<1` is sufficient.

Ultimately, try [random](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/) of C++11.

`srand(time(NULL));` may be a cause of trouble if you plan to use many threads : `time(NULL)` only changes once in a second, and many threads will get the same value. Send a seed to the thread or use a [random_device](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/random_device/) to seed your random generator.

Comment: related: [Why do people say there is modulo bias when using a random number generator?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10984974/4279)

Comment: [the last picture](https://www.wakari.io/sharing/bundle/jfs/Test%20PRNG%20using%20gray%20bitmap) illustrates the modulo bias issue.