# floating point random number in c++

Tags: c++, random, numbers

hi i am trying to write a code for random numbers between -1 and 1 like :
0.9
0.3
0.8
but i can get only numbers like 1 2 3 5 etc using this code

```
rand()%(max-min + 1) + min
```

is there any direct function in c++ .if not how can i achieve it

the complete programis :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class perceptron{
    public:
        vector <float> weights;
        int max=5,min=1;
        perceptron( float n){
            for( int i=0 ;i< n; i++){

                weights.push_back(rand()%(max-min + 1) + min);
                cout<<weights[i]<<",";
        }
    }
};
int main(){
    perceptron p1(4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since a couple of years back C++ has very good [facilities for pseudo-random number generation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), that can handle any type.

Comment: See [C++ random float number generation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17798317/1708801)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, C++ has very good facilities for generating random real numbers.

See this code:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::random_device randdev;
    std::mt19937 generator(randdev());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> distrib(-1, 1);
    std::cout << distrib(generator) << '\n';
}
```

You do need to use a recent version of C++, though (C++11).