# Generating random float number in C++ doesn't work (Visual studio 2013)

Tags: c++, random, visual-studio-2013, floating-point

I know there are many duplicates of this question around but my problem is different. What I am trying to do is generating a simple random float number in the range [-0.5, 0.5]. What I have been using is the formula expressed in this link:

[C++ random float number generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686353/c-random-float-number-generation)

I need two different random float numbers `jitter_dx` and `jitter_dy`. According to the formula of the link above I have:

```
float jitter_dx = -0.5f + static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / (0.5f - (-0.5f))));
float jitter_dy = -0.5f + static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / (0.5f - (-0.5f))));
```

Now, my problem is weird because when I try to debug the code, `jitter_dx` seems being always the same (or slightly different) while `jitter_dy` is generated quite randomly. I hereby give you the values of both `jitter_dx` and `jitter_dy` during 10 different debugging sessions:

0.213156521,
0.123004854

0.215659022,
0.323389411

0.216849267,
0.259575188

0.217856407,
-0.460295409

0.218955040,
0.147907972

0.220358908,
-0.259910882

0.221335471,
0.0202490091

0.224143207,
0.204702914

0.225333393,
0.140888691

As you can see `jitter_dx` is always (almost) the same. Both values are calculated one right after the other one, without any code in the middle. May you help me finding the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So MSVC's implementation of `rand()` is horrible. No surprise here. Use the modern `<random>` facilities instead.

Comment: Are you calling `srand` function before using `rand`?

Comment: FWIW, g++ on linux fairs a little bit better: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61f5ee1e5b16530e But seriously, just don't use `rand` anymore, the nineties are over.

Comment: I am curious, the next two answers(*including mine*) include alternatives including using the C++11 random header and boost, both of these will work in MSVC 2013 so why not use either of these? In my answer I explain why using `rand` is not advised, including possible poor implementations.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour my apologies for not reading carefully your answer in that post. I ingenuously assumed that rand() was a correct way and therefore I guessed the problem was related to Visual Studio. My fault. I upvoted your answer there! Sorry once more..

Comment: No worries, it is a good idea to keep in mind that the accepted answer may not always be the perfect one for your case. The answer being accepted just means it solved the OPs problem but especially with older answers you will often find more general or up to date answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the sequence produced by MSVC's implementation of `rand` after the common `srand(time(NULL))` depends in a very predictable way on the time, in the sense that a small change in time (with small as in small compared to the time between 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970 and 03:14:07 UTC on 19 January 2038) will lead to very similar resulting sequences.

If you insist on using `rand`, discard the first couple hundred or thousand values it produces. Then the results will at least look better (while still being terrible).

What you really should do is use the modern [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) (or [boost.random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_random.html) if you cannot use C++11) facilities, for your application [`std::uniform_real_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution).

For further information, [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) is an interesting watch.

Comment: Really useful! Problem solved with <random>, thanks a lot!

Comment: It is a little disappointing that the C++11 solution was only two answers down including the same STL video link.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I agree, I already went there and upvoted your answer. Should definitely be on top over there.