# Random number between zero and one in c++

Tags: c++, random

i want to create a random number between 0 and 1 but my codes output is zero.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  srand(time(0));

  for(int x=0;x<100;x++)
  {
      cout<<(rand()%10)/10<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you intend to have the integer division there?

Comment: I recommend you use [modern C++ random number facilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution) instead of `rand()`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686353/c-random-float-number-generation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This: `(rand()%10)/10` gives you a (low quality) random integer between zero and RAND_MAX, then you use modulo to turn that into a (biased) integer between zero and nine, then you perform integer division by 10 which will always be a value less than 1 which will be truncated to zero.

A much better solution would be to use the random facilities from C++11 and use a `std::uniform_real_distribution` to obtain your value between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

You are dividing an int. Anything lower than one will be cut to 0. You need to declare/cast a double or float (to have decimals).

Comment: No - even casting to float or double won't give you an uniform distributed random number between 0 and 1

Comment: @jhilmer I only answered part of the question (why the output is 0). Actually there is not actual question to begin with so i did just give him a hint to try and correct his code. I should have added that this is not the solution to the whole problem.