# Logic : How to print Pseudo_random bit sequence pattern in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

Really, i want to get random bit sequence pattern, please tell me logic how to get sequence pattern.

I tried with below (example) code for getting Random bit sequence pattern like this

```
2147483663, 1073741831, 536870915, 2415919105, 1207959552, 2751463424, 3523215360, 1761607680, 3028287488, 3661627392, 1830813696
```

But i am getting only constant value, without any change like this

```
1932117999, 1932117999, 1932117999, 1932117999, 1932117999, 1932117999, 1932117999, 1932117999, 1932117999, 1932117999
```

Please find the attachment and suggest me. I am grateful.

```
int main()
{
  unsigned int x=12131222, y=898565;
  unsigned int z=58964796, c=6543217;
  unsigned long long t, result;
  unsigned int r;
  int i;

  x = 14900243 * x+ 123456789;
  y ^= y << 21;
  y ^= y >> 17;
  y ^= y << 30;

  /* Do not set y=0! */

  t = 42945843 * z + c;
  c = t >> 32;
  z = t;

  result=(unsigned int)(x>>32) + (unsigned int)y +z;

  for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
  {
    r = result; //use the LFSR
    printf ("%u, ", r);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your loop does not modify `result` but just prints it 10 times. How should the value change? You need to perform your operations each time you execute the loop.

Comment: I suspect `(unsigned int)(x>>32) + (unsigned int)y +z;` needs to be done using wider math and with `<<`.  `result=(1ULL*x)<<32) + y +z;`

Comment: `t = 42945843 * z + c;` only assigned `t` a value in the `unsigned` range.  Again, wider math needed.  What is the source or your LFSR algorithm?

Comment: Can i use register concept for random bit sequence pattern. Actually i need to implement this program in hardware.

Source Code
` 
void Polynomial_lfsr(int &dout)
{


 static int reg;
int pattern;
 int load_data =0xACF5;
int i=0;
 reg = load_data;

 for (i=0;i<=32;i++)
 {

        pattern= ((reg >> 0) ^ (reg >> 2) ^ (reg >> 3) ^ (reg >> 5) ) & 1;
        reg =  (reg >> 1) | (bit << 15);

        reg[i] = pattern; // assigns the feedback polynomial result to bit zero of the LFSR
        dout = reg;

         }

}`
How can i insert  sequence pattern into above code.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create special function for it.
Secondly, use static variable for save progress at each iteration.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long random()
{
        static unsigned int x =12131222, y=898565;
        static unsigned int z=58964796, c=6543217;
        unsigned long long t, result;
        x = 14900243 * x+ 123456789;
        y ^= y << 21;
        y ^= y >> 17;
        y ^= y << 30;
        /* Do not set y=0! */
        t = 42945843 * z + c;
        c = t >> 32;
        z = t;
        return result=(unsigned int)(x>>32) + (unsigned int)y +z;
}
int main()
{
        unsigned int r;
        int i;
        for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
                r = random(); //use the LFSR
                printf ("%u, ", r);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Or move your code inside loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        unsigned int x =12131222, y=898565;
        unsigned int z=58964796, c=6543217;
        unsigned long long t, result;

        unsigned int r;
        int i;
        for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
                x = 14900243 * x+ 123456789;
                y ^= y << 21;
                y ^= y >> 17;
                y ^= y << 30;
                /* Do not set y=0! */
                t = 42945843 * z + c;
                c = t >> 32;
                z = t;
                result=(unsigned int)(x>>32) + (unsigned int)y +z;
                r = result; //use the LFSR
                printf ("%u, ", r);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can i use register concept for random bit sequence pattern. Actually i need to implement this program in hardware. Source Code ` void Polynomial_lfsr(int &dout) { static int reg; int pattern; int load_data =0xACF5; int i=0; reg = load_data; for (i=0;i<=32;i++) { pattern= ((reg >> 0) ^ (reg >> 2) ^ (reg >> 3) ^ (reg >> 5) ) & 1; reg = (reg >> 1) | (bit << 15); reg[i] = pattern; // assigns the feedback polynomial result to bit zero of the LFSR dout = reg; } }` How can i insert sequence pattern into above code

Comment: Update question, please. Very difficult to understand code without formatting

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you should not write your own pseudo random number code. Use srand() for seeding and rand() for computation as shown for example here: [C++ random float number generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686353/c-random-float-number-generation)
There are still options with better quality random numbers, but this is a starting point.

Comment: I cant use srand() in VIVADO HLS. So i am trying with LFSR.

Comment: Still, you need to think about seeding.