# How to use random precision numbers

Tags: c++

Hello I need help writing my program. I am trying to figure out how I should make it so when I type two range numbers (one is a maximum and one is a minimum) which the program will recognize and output a random number in between one of them. So far I have figured it out but it works only for whole numbers, I cant seem to find a way for those numbers to be with precision of 2 lets say.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
int  a, b, c, d;
srand(time(0));
cout << "Welcome to the game." << endl;
cout << "Please enter number range" << endl;
cout << "Highest number:";
cin >> c;
cout << "Lowest number:";
cin >> d;
b = d + (rand() % (c - d + 1));
cout << "Enter your guess:";
cin >> a;
unsigned int count = 0;
while (a < b) {
    cout << "Your number is lower than the correct one." << endl;
    cout << "Please try again:";
    cin >> a;
    count++;
}
while (a > b) {
    cout << "Your number is higher than the correcnt one." << endl;
    cout << "Please try again:";
    cin >> a;
    count++;
}

cout << "Your number is the correct one!!! You guessed it on " << count << " time" << endl;
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ random float number generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686353/c-random-float-number-generation)

Comment: Note that your program doesn't do what you probably think it does. If you guess too high and then too low, it will tell you that you guessed correctly.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am a beginner, I have just started studying c++ yesterday. Every suggestion would be a good thing for me.

Comment: C++ does not have a "precision of 2" data type, as it does integer types.  You should read up on C++ floating point types, and possibly on decimal type libraries.  It's not clear from your question which you are pursuing, so I am not closing this as the proposed duplicate.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution

Comment: BTW, floating point variables are stored internally with maximum precision.  You can *output* them with whatever precision you want.  If you want the values stored with a given precision, you'll have to truncate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::uniform_real_distribution` to generate random floating point:

```
std::random_device device;
std::mt19937 generator(device());
std::uniform_real_distribution<> distribution(least, greatest);
double a_random_number = distribution(generator);
```

> I cant seem to find a way for those numbers to be with precision of 2 lets say.

Simply round the result to nearest value.

But be aware that typical floating point representations cannot precisely represent all decimal numbers such as 0.1 etc.