# Seeded random that has floats as input and output for possible recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, random, seed, random-seed

I am looking for a seeded solution to be able to reproduce results.
I need a random float between 0 and 1 for each recursive run of my method, so I need to use the previous seed or float to produce a new random float or seed.
So I am in need of a seeded seed generator or a seeded float generator where the seed is a float.
Any ideas?

Comment: I hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686353/random-float-number-generation

Comment: It seems to focus on making a random from a pseudo-random, which is not what I am trying to do, thanks anyway :)

Comment: Can you explain what application you are making that requires a generator you describe?

Comment: I am trying to visualize a tree and need a slight irregularity at each branch, and I need to be able to recreate the exact same tree with a seed

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
// crypto-strong random num in rage [0,1)
let random = ()=> crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0]/2**32; 

function recursive(n,rand) {
  return n>0 ? recursive(n-1, rand/2) : rand;
}

console.log( recursive(5,random()) );
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is just a seeded PRNG.

You just have to hard-code the seed and then call it in order.

```js
// rewrite of https://gist.github.com/blixt/f17b47c62508be59987b
class Random {
  constructor( seed ) {
    this._seed = seed % 0x7fffffff;
    if (this._seed <= 0) { this._seed += 0x7ffffffe; }
  }
  next() {
    const next_int = this._seed =
      this._seed * 0x41a7 % 0x7fffffff;

    return ( next_int - 1 ) / 0x80000000;
  }
}

const my_seed = 42; // just hard-code this
const rand = new Random( my_seed );

let i = 0;
while( i++ < 5 ) {
  console.log( rand.next() );
}
/*
  0.000328707043081522
  0.524587101303041
  0.735423531383276
  0.2633055401965976
  0.37622397067025304
*/
```

If you ever wish to make it return the value at *n*-th iteration, then just create a new instance with the same seed and call it *n* times before getting the value.

```js
// rewrite of https://gist.github.com/blixt/f17b47c62508be59987b
class Random {
  constructor( seed ) {
    this._seed = seed % 0x7fffffff;
    if (this._seed <= 0) { this._seed += 0x7ffffffe; }
  }
  next() {
    const next_int = this._seed =
      this._seed * 0x41a7 % 0x7fffffff;

    return ( next_int - 1 ) / 0x80000000;
  }
}

function getRandAtIndex( index = 0, seed ) {
  const gen = new Random( seed );
  let i = 0;
  while( i++ < index ) {
    gen.next();
  }
  return gen.next();
}

// this time we use a random seed
const my_seed = Math.random() * 0xFFFFFFFF;
const rand = new Random( my_seed );

// log the five first values
let i = 0;
while( i++ < 5 ) {
  console.log( rand.next() );
}

console.log( '\nthird value was', getRandAtIndex( 2, my_seed ) );
```