# How can I generate random numbers between -1 and 1 using Linear Congruent Generator (LCG) method?

Tags: python, random, random-seed

The following source code (written by me) generates random numbers between 0 and 1:

```
def nextRandom(seed):
    m = 233280 # modulus
    a = 9301 # multiplier
    c = 49297 # increment
    x0 = seed # start-value
    return ((a * x0 + c) % m)/m
```

What modification can I apply to this source code to generate random numbers between -1 and 1?

Comment: What about `2*(((a * x0 + c) % m)/m) - 1`? But this will probably introduce a bias?

Comment: @DarrylG, can u supply me any reference?

Comment: @user366312--[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686353/random-float-number-generation)--check  1st answer to see how floating random numbers are generated in a range from LO to HI from an integer random number generator.